# React Native Error: undefined is not an object when passing data to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting an error when passing data to my component with props and trying to access it from there.
I have my data in the following format

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Test',
    price: 1500,

  },
];
```

I import it and pass the data like via props this:

```
const post0 = data[0];
...
<Post post={post0}/>
```

In my component I receive the data succesfully which I can verify via log like this `console.log(props);` and get the following log entry

```
{"post": {"id": "0", "price": "1500", "title": "Test"}}
```

When I now try to access a certain property like id in my component

```
<Text> { props.post.id } </Text>
```

I get the error 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.post.title')'

How can I use the data in my component? I am assuming I somehow have to map the data but couldn't resolve it.

Comment: Likely you have a wrapping issues try props.post0 or props.post.post0 otherwise you have error at some other place and you need to provide full components code…

Comment: I can access props.post as well (wtihout any brackets). When I log it I get {"id": "0", "price": "1500", "title": "Test"} I just cannot access any of the nested properties like I tried with props.post.id

Comment: @peldroid Can you give more information about <Text> component? If not that, try using a <p> tag instead and see if the value is getting printed.

Comment: it is standard react-native Text component. same error comes for <p> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.
I used the post component in my code a second time without any props so therefore it was indeed undefined. Getting the object properties like {post.id} works perfectly fine when always having an object handed to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Is your component a class based component or a functional component? If it is a class based component, you should access your props using "this" keyword. For example

```
export class Post extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <View>
      <Text>{this.props.post.id}</Text>
      <Text>{this.props.post.title}</Text>
     </View>
    )
  }

}
```

If it is a functional component, you can access the props directly. For example:

```
export function Post(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.post.id}</Text>
      <Text>{props.post.title}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I have a functional component which looks exactly like your example but somehow I still get the undefined error